# bootstrap-validator custom validation and ajax request return on success/ok

Tags: jquery, ajax-request, bootstrapvalidator-1000hz

I use bootstrap-validator(http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator) and need display error message if ajax request is successful and has status 'ok'.(customer exists so to speak).

How can I return on ajax request and get it working with validator?
Here is current code:

```
  $('form').validator({
      custom: {
          business: function($el) {
              var input_value = $el.val();
              if(input_value.length > 5){
                var result2;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/customers/'+input_value,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        (data.status == 'ok' ? $(".nahtavad").prop('disabled', true) : $(".nahtavad").prop('disabled', false));
                        // if i return here it does nothing and does not display error.
                        return 'This customer exits'
                        }else {
                            $(".nahtavad").prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                      $("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', false);
                      $(".nahtavad").prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
              }
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's was not possible to return on ajax request so, added this check after length control and now it's working as should be:

```
if($(".nahtavad").is('[disabled]') === true){
   return 'Error';
}
```